# SAPUI5: How to create a control hierarchy?

Tags: sapui5

I hope you can help me with this. After reading all the documentation several times, googling for days, etc I don't find the way to do what i'm going to explain in a clean way, and in think I'm missing something because it's a really basic scenario.

I'm working with oData models, in this case 2 named models, "Model1", "Model2". Now what I want is to show a "parent" ComboBox based on an oData path, and a table that changes its items depending on the selection, in other words.

```
Model1 { //JSON representation of the data.
 Accounts:[
  "account 1": {invoices: ["invoice1", "invoice2", "invoice3"]},
  "account 2": {invoices:["invoice4", "invoice5"]}
 ]
}
```

Combo Box:

```
<... items={Model1>/Accounts} /> -- This works and shows Account 1, and Account2.
```

Table

```
<Table... items="{Model1>Invoices}">
..
<items>
....
</items>
</Table>
```

What I want is the table to change it's context to the account selected on the ComboBox. The point is that this works, but the first time it loads the view, as there is no account selected, it calls the wrong odata path MYSERVICE/Invoices, instead of doing nothing, as the Account is not set yet, and the path for the invoices, once selected the account, shoud be MYSERVICE/Account('Account1')/Invoices for example.

I know I can achieve this with code, but I'm sure there must be a clean way to do this.

Seriously, this is driving me crazy.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the question as the "code" was not escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that

```
items="{Model1>Invoices}"
```

triggers odata call? Because this is a relative path (without leading slash), normally it should not do the call.

What you can do:

1. Handle ComboBox [selectionChange](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ComboBox.html#event:selectionChange%20selectionChange) event;
2. In this event handler, create a path that you will bound the table to. In your case the path could look like this: "/Account(Account1)" - "/{EntitySetName}({KEY})". You can make use of [createKey](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html#createKey) method of [ODataModel2](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html);
3. Set the table's context using the path:

   `oTable.bindObject({
       path: sPath,
       model: "Model1",
       parameters: {
           $expand: "Invoices"
       }
   });`
4. Once the context is set, the relative binding will start working automatically and table will get the "Invoices"

I assume that the Account and Invoices are linked via navigation property and one-to-many cardinality, that's why the **$expand** parameter will load the corresponding invoices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although is a relative path, it's using it's grand parent context as current path. I didn't explained that, suppose that Account has a parent that is User, and the user context is Set, then the binding resolves to User(1)/Invoices which does not exists :(

Your approach is similar to mine, but cleaner, however it still needs to 'hardcode' the relationship.

Comment: I'm afraid that it is not possible to do all this stuff declaratively in XML view, unfortunately you have to set bindings from the JS. However you can try to use a hack, you can set the same model but with different names for GrandParent, Parent and Child (if needed). In this case the Table will not have a root context, so the relative path won't be resolved.

Comment: I also tried that! And it worked, but I thought it wasn't too optimal hehe. Then, If the only way is coding, I'll do it that way. Thank you very much!